# How do I plug in external data from a database ( say MongoDb ) to a Cucumber Feature file's Scenario outline ? Is it even possible?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

Basically I am trying to externalize the data given to the scenario steps, and instead of hard-coding it in the Scenario outline, I would like to read it from an external source/Database. How should I go about implementing this ?
I am using cucumber with the TestNg framework.